# How do I pipe to Linux split command?

Tags: linux, split, pipe

I'm a bit useless at Linux CLI, and I am trying to run the following commands to randomly sort, then split a file with output file prefixes 'out' (one output file will have 50 lines, the other the rest):

```
sort -R somefile  | split -l 50 out
```

I get the error

```
split: cannot open ‘out’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

this is presumably because the third parameter of split should be its input file. How do I pass the result of the sort to split? TIA!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `-` for stdin:

```
sort -R somefile  | split -l 50 - out
```

From `man split`:

> Output  fixed-size  pieces  of INPUT to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...; default size is 1000 lines, and default PREFIX is 'x'.  With no
>          INPUT, **or when INPUT is -**, read standard input.

Allowing `-` to specify *input is stdin* is a convention many UNIX utilities follow.

Comment: Actually it works without having to specify to read from `stdin` as `-`, am i missing something here?

Comment: No it does not. Without the `-` you wouldn't be able to specify a prefix for the output files - which is the 4th parameter.  That's what the question was about afaik.

Comment: I just thought it was a wrong inclusion of the file `out` that caused the issue

Comment: Thanks for your help. If any one else is trying to do a similar thing, split does not produce two files, this does: sort -R /media/ed/Seagate/data/test/t.txt | csplit -s - 51.

Comment: For me, I get `split: -: cannot determine file size` (I'm piping `tail -n+2 ...` to `split`)

Comment: @davemyron That's interesting. You are on MacOS?

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, but I think the cause (though I'd still consider it a bug) is that I was trying to L-chunk it (`-n l/3` for example) which requires knowing the total size.

Comment: Sure, in that case you need to temporary store the output from tail into a file. It's not a bug.

Answer (score 6):

`out` is interpreted as input file. You can should a single dash to indicate reading from `STDIN`:

`sort -R somefile | split - -l 50 out`

Comment: Sorry the other answer was first, I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

For POSIX systems like mac os the `-` parameter is not accepted and you need to completely omit the filename, and let it generate it's own names.

```
sort -R somefile | split -l 50
```